# Show that there is a countable collection of open balls $B$ such that $\mathscr{B}(X)$ = $\sigma (B)$

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, d)$ be a separable metric space and $\mathscr{B}(X)$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Show that there is a countable collection of open balls $B$ such that $\mathscr{B}(X)$ = $\sigma (B)$

We know that since X is a separable metric space then it has a countable dense subset $ D $, so for each $ z \in D $ and we take a ball of radius $ r $, $ B (z, r) $.
We note that the collection of balls centered at $ z \in D $ is countable and it also happens that $ \bigcup_{z \in D} B (z, r) = X $

Then we propose $ B $ as $$ B = \{B(z,r)| z\in D \}$$
My question is that if I can directly state that as the balls are open then they generate the Borelians of $X$ and consequently it is given that
$$\mathscr{B}(X) = \sigma (B)$$

Comment: I presume you are restricting to rational values of $r$?  Note that it will suffice to show that any open set may be written as a (necessarily countable) union of such balls.

Comment: The fact that your open balls are open only shows that $\mathcal{B}(X) \supset \sigma(B)$.  The other direction is the less trivial one.

Comment: If I am assuming that $ r $ is rational, this is to ensure that it is countable, I suppose that the other contention consists in seeing that any open one can be seen as the open countable union of balls, is that right?

Comment: Yes, right.  Well, not just a countable union of balls, but a countable union of balls that are centered at points of $D$ and having rational radius.